# Learning Zend Framework 1 or 2?

Tags: frameworks, zend-framework

I have programmed for a few years in php and now I'm going to learn zend framwork.
Zend is very popular and there are a lot of tutorials, books and documentation out there. But I saw in the last months that there is a second version of Zend, but it's not so used and popular, not yet.

I think it is better to start with a new version, but I don't know what to do now, as when I see job offers many people require the first version.
Which version do you suggest me?

Comment: Although I did answer below, you should try modifying this question to be less narrowly scoped.  Mentioning a specific framework and specific version numbers makes this question less useful to others.  Try rewording it to ask "Should I use the previous, or the future version of a framework/dependency?"

Comment: first take a look at Simfony 2. compared to Zend it's a breeze to work with.

Answer (score 4):

You should learn both, but I'd personally put more emphasis on ZF2.

ZF2 is the package that will have the longest lifespan ahead of it, whilst ZF1 is probably going to go into maintained mode once ZF2 is generally available, so if you limit yourself to ZF1 you'll eventually have to learn ZF2 anyway if you want to maintain your employability.  If you only learn ZF1, you're dooming yourself to the life of a maintainance engineer keeping legacy codebases in working order.

Having said that, it would be unwise to ignore ZF1 as nearly all Zend Framework applications currently deployed will use that.

Answer (score 1):

ZF2 appears to be in beta; this will add additional overhead to your daily routine, as you might often have to update previously written code with each subsequent beta release (which could be often).

With that said, if you're looking at starting a long term project, that overhead may be worth it.  I ran into this dilemma a while ago with Symfony2, and decided I did not want to start a new project with a framework that will have no LTS.

If you simply want to learn this to increase your employability, you won't likely see any benefits for a year or more.  As it stands, no companies will be running ZF2 for a production application, and it is unlikely that many will want to migrate their ZF1 application immediately (or at all) after the release of ZF2.

Comment: ok, so if I would to learn zend now is better start to the first version?

Comment: or is better start to learn another framework? because if I start now, time to learn it and do some practice, the actual beta version could be the one of the future.
So, i would prefer a framework LTS, useful and popular for find job without problem. you suggest me to change framework, like symfony (1 or 2?), or learn Zend 1?
thank you so much

Comment: Well again, that is completely up to you depending on what your end goal is. If you want to learn a next-generation framework, but want to be able to use it NOW, then Symfony2 might be your best bet, as has been public ally released for months now.

Answer (score -2):

To update the status on here, there is no point learning Zend Framework 1 now. It is End of Life and ZF2 is mature enough for all uses.

Comment: Anyone care to comment why they're down voting?